# Refresh CSS ellipsis when resizing container

Tags: jquery-ui, css, resize, ellipsis

I'm using jQuery UI and have setup a table to resize columns.

```
span {      
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I apply some simple ellipsis to the cells so that when they are too small I get the ...

If I look at the page it looks like:

[image]

When I resize the column however, it doesn't re-apply the ellipsis :(

[image]

Is there a simple way to do this? I tried removing the overflow by making it visible, then re-applying it to be hidden, but the ellipsis goes back to the original view when rendered.

Comment: Maybe this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs

Comment: Thanks @user2258152 - issue turned out to be that the cell was a fixed width and resized with javascript. Changing to min-width solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Table Cell had a fixed width in CSS:

`width: 120px;`

Which was then resized with JavaScript. When the resizing happens the cell content in the cell stayed the same width.

Changing the CSS to be `min-width: 120px;` and resizing with JavaScript from `width` to `min-width` solved the problem.