# CSS: Inline div with min-width that comes after another Div of variable width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get something similar to the following code:

```
<div class="window-width-container">
    <div class="head">head</div>
    <div class="tail">(tail)</div>

    <div class="head">head head head head head</div>
    <div class="tail">(tail)</div>

    <div class="head">head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head </div>
    <div class="tail">(tail)</div>
</div>
```

To output:

```
+------------------------------------+
+head(tail)                          +
+head head head head head(tail)      +
+head head head head head he...(tail)+
+------------------------------------+
```

Where the following constraints are in place:

- The head div has inline-block behavior (i.e. the width is flexible to the content)
- The tail div follows immediately after
- Both divs fit in one line, with head being ellipsized if it gets too large

I can almost get the behavior working if I use tables instead of divs, but once I use

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

to get that ellipsis behavior, it insteads does overflow and pushes past the bounds of the container div.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `max-width` on the head div?

Comment: sorry I misspoke, the container div needs to be 100% width and I don't want to use javascript to figure out the window width

Comment: flexible widths and ellipsis are huge problem in css and often don't work as desired. But maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/CNkJ4/1/ if its fine for you

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to utilize the full 100% if possible. The best example I can show is this: http://jsfiddle.net/yu62p/ however the head spills over into multiple rows and I need it to truncate

Comment: Updated the answer, just update max-width: 100% in head

Comment: That would cause the tail to spill over to the next line though. I need it all to fit on the same line within the 100% space.

Comment: you can change the max-width to head to say 90% and specify min-width as 5% to tail depending on your requirement

Comment: That might add the potential for the tail to not be able to fit the full contents.

Comment: This -almost- does what I want except I cannot get the ellipsis to work http://jsfiddle.net/Aa6kv/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

Add wrapper class around head tail

```
<div class="window-width-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">head</div>
        <div class="tail">(tail)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">head head head head head</div>
        <div class="tail">(tail)</div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="head">head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head head</div>
        <div class="tail">(tail)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.window-width-container {
    width: 100%
}
.wrapper {
    flex: 1;
}
.head, .tail {
    display: inline-block;
}
.head {
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.tail {
    min-width: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/CNkJ4/6/)