# CSS ellipsis not working for this div

Tags: css

A representative code sample:

```
<div style="width:300px; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap;">
    <ul>
         <li>Long name: <span>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/G57LE/

It seems only the overflow property will do anything here.

How do I get the text to do an ellipsis on overflow for this div (where the ellipsis happens just before the end of the div)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because the text isn't in the div itself.  You would have to apply the width and overflow attributes to the span itself.

Possible solution for you: [CSS text ellipsis when using variable width divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs)

Answer (score 0):

add  this

`display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; width:300px;`

to span's class `.value`

here is http://jsfiddle.net/G57LE/5/