# CSS text ellipsis and 100 percent width

Tags: html, css

I have the following container of text:

```
<div class="cardTitles">

<div class="title">
    <div class="titleContent">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <b>Some long long long title here</b>
        <a href="some href"></a>
    </div>
</div>

... title divs ...

</div>
```

**css**:

```
.cardTitles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.title
{
    position: relative;

    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I want to make text full width + text-overflow: ellipsis. So when I resize browser all `title` divs should be full 100% width of the parent `cardTitles` with cut text to three dots at the end.

I found that this is possible using flex. Here is the possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs):

```
.parent-div {
    display: flex;
}

.text-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    

    min-width: 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work for me. Parent container stops resizing when it reach the max length of some child title.

---

You can find an example here: `http://88.198.106.150/tips/cpp/`

Try to resize browser and look at title with text: `What does it mean that a reference must refer to an object, not a dereferenced NULL pointer`. I need to make it overflow ellipsis.

Comment: Nice! Cool trick thankyou, even works in a flexible width table, fantastic.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this out:

```css
.titleContent {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Here's and [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkh7yhw3/)

Comment: There is title with text: 'What does it mean that a reference must refer to an object, not a dereferenced NULL pointer'. Try to resize browser and you will see the result

Comment: You have to apply the ellipsis property on the anchor tag  <a data-url="refs-not-null" href="cpp/refs-not-null"></a>

Comment: It didn't help me :( When I just leave text inside `titleContent` it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: A bit old but still: Can you make it work here for example? https://jsfiddle.net/k9ew7ry2/17/ The text with the red background ... It won't work with columns/column-count setting on one of the parents ..

Comment: Change the display of .item to block. Seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/k9ew7ry2/29/

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to work when you put it within a flexbox :(

Comment: @FrankFajardo It does work within a flexbox. http://jsfiddle.net/97rh1dfx/

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: If the item at the end (in this case the a tag) has content and the middle text is very very long, the a tag will overflow and not be vissible.

Answer (score 25):

No Flex but could work also ... try it.

```
.element {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.truncate {
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[text-overflow ellipsis with 100% width](https://gist.github.com/elky/ce230d6fcab055104cdf1a3358037fc7)

Answer (score 7):

The width needs to be added in pixels, percentage wont work along with other three properties as given below:-

```
.text-ellipsis{
    max-width: 160px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: That's unfortunately. Kind of kills responsive design. :(

Comment: @user959690 You can use `max-width: calc(100%);` for responsive design.

Comment: @Ron that doesn't do anything useful

Answer (score 2):

```css
#div1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: clip;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#div2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 12em;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p>The following two divs contains a long text that will not fit in the box. As you can see, the text is clipped.</p>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:clip":</p>
<div id="div1">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>

<p>This div uses "text-overflow:ellipsis":</p>
<div id="div2">This is some long text that will not fit in the box</div>
```

Comment: @Odenir Gomes: While edits are welcome to fix typos, we are not allowed to change the original code. If you've found bugs or have suggestions for improved code examples, feel free to post a separate reply or suggest an edit via comment.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:

```
  div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: calc(100% - 1px);
  }
```

Comment: It does not work either