# CSS: display: inline-flex and text-overflow: ellipsis not working togethier

Tags: html, css

I have a `span`. I need both the below mentioned styles. But along with `display: inline-flex`, `text-overflow: ellipsis` is not working.

```
.ed-span{
   display: inline-flex!important;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
 }
```

when I change `inline-flex` to `inline-block` it is working. But I need `inline-flex`.

How can i make it work?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: The response is available here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649904/css-text-ellipsis-when-using-variable-width-divs answered by @Blender

Comment: We need your HTML or a demo please.

Answer (score 38):

I ran into the same issue. What you have to do is put the text within another div which has the overflow style. The inline-flex does not support text-overflow as seen here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=912434

This should work:

```
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="text-div">
    Ellipsis' are cool.
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the text-div style is as follows:

```
.text-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

And parent-div:

```
.parent-div {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: This solution helped me on an another issue where I couldn't use anything else

Comment: Just a note that I managed to resolve an issue using this solution, but on the parent element I had to specify `min-length: 0` in the CSS

Comment: anything with max-width: 200px is a hack, will look elsewhere

Comment: @martin I think you mean min-width: 0;

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use min-width: 0 on the display: flex element
See full article here:
https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: inline-grid` in `parent-div`.

```css
.parent-div {
  display: inline-grid;
  background: cyan;
}

span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<label class="parent-div">
      <span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, itaque,
            at error rerum ab facere cupiditate veniam incidunt modi temporibus
            explicabo earum minima facilis a excepturi laborum similique
      </span>
</label>
```