# CSS3 flexbox layout with ellipsis doesn't work on mobile Safari

Tags: css, flexbox, mobile-safari

The following demo (submitted as an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12656699/467874)) illustrates usage of ellipsis with flexbox layout. However, it doesn't seem to work on mobile Safari - the text is not shortened at all (tested on iPhone 5, iPhone X and iOS 11.4 emulator in XCode). It works on all desktop browsers including Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/kXMz7/1/

```css
.parent-div {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.text-div {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    
    min-width: 0;
}

.icon-div {
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="icon-div">X</div>
  <div class="text-div">This is text I'd like to truncate when space doesn't permit</div>
</div>
```

Is this a known problem?

Comment: I would try putting that text in another span and then put the ellipsis on the span (with display inline block and max-width 100%;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow, sets width to truncate the characters when the given width isn't enough.

Although while using flex, setting 'width' is not recommended. I just added `flex-basis: 40%;` in 'text-div' class and I could see the truncation happening.